# Interface with generic type - is it over engineered?

Tags: java, interface

We have an interface in existing code which is confusing me, or I'm not able to understand it properly.

This is the interface declaration

```
public interface EmployeeMother<EmployeeMotherT extends EmployeeMother, EmpTargetT>{

    EmployeeMotherT fromJsonSchema();
    
    EmployeeMotherT withCompleteDetails();
    
    EmpTargetT> build();
}
```

What does this `<EmployeeMotherT extends EmployeeMother, EmpTargetT>` mean?

Below pasted is the implementation of this interface

```
public class EmployeeFormMother extends EmployeeFormBuilder<EmployeeForm>
    implements EmployeeMother<EmployeeFormMother,EmployeeForm>{
    
    public EmployeeFormMother fromJsonSchema(){
       .....
    
       return this;
    }
    
    public EmployeeFormMother fromJsonSchema(){
       ....
    
       return this;
    }
    
    public EmployeeFormMother fromJsonSchema(){
        return this;
    }
    
    public EmployeeForm build(){
       ...
    
       return super.build();  
    }
}
```

What does this  `implements EmployeeMother<EmployeeFormMother,EmployeeForm>` mean in the implementing class?

Comment: Please, provide compilable code.

Comment: Mother1 can have a daughter and then that daughter can be mother2 to her daughter... it's just a linked list by the looks of it. Also after a certain age, maybe you mark someone has grandmother and she has a few more fields, or a few less

Comment: What is the actual question? How to understand it, or whether it's "overengineered"?

Comment: "`EmployeeMotherT extends EmployeeMother`" is a raw-typed upper bound. It's not a good idea to use raw types. It should be something like `EmployeeMotherT extends EmployeeMother<EmployeeMotherT>`.

Comment: There's nothing special about this, just basic generic notation. The only unusual is that the type placeholders are pretty wordy; it might be more usual to see sth. like `EmployeeMother<M extends EmployeeMother, T>`

Comment: For formal type parameters in generic method signatures, the widely expected convention is that they should be very short: 1 or 2 letters only.  For example, `List<T>` where T is understood to be short for "some type".  Wordy formal type parameters greatly harm readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does this `<EmployeeMotherT extends EmployeeMother, EmpTargetT>`
> mean?

`<EmployeeMotherT extends EmployeeMother, EmpTargetT>` means there are two generic types involved:

- EmployeeMotherT which extends EmployeeMother
- EmpTargetT

> what does this `implements EmployeeMother<EmployeeFormMother,EmployeeForm>` mean in the
> implementing class?

It means that this class will deliver concrete implementations for the defined method stumps in the interface. It also means that in this context `EmployeeFormMother` must be a subtype of `EmployeeMother` and also that `EmployeeForm` a subtype of `EmpTargetT`.